# El informe no tiene tablas Crystal Report C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedure, crystal-reports, dataset

vengo nuevamente a buscar su ayuda ya que ahora me encuentro con 2 problemas al momento de enviar los datos recolectados a mi subreporte como lo describo en el titulo, tengo este error que describo aquí en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente al primer error me encuentro con otro que consiste que nuevamente me pide los datos que envió al subreporte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el código que estoy usando y que funciona cuando lo envió directamente a un solo reporte y no como en estos instantes que lo hago a través de subreportes

```
  private void FormReporteAdmMensual_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        try
        {
            String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                try
                {
                    ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                    myConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SISTEMAS-PC";
                    myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "SISROL";
                    myConnectionInfo.UserID = "TECNOLOGIA";
                    myConnectionInfo.Password = "tecnologia";
                    myConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;
                    String filePath = @"Z:\Sisrol-Net\Reportes\ReporteMensualAdm3Meses.rpt";                        
                    //Cargar el Reporte
                    rd.Load(filePath);                       
                    //Asignarle al Reporte el DataSet                    
                    rd.SetDataSource(RolAdm3Mes(fechin, fechfin,"0930159520"));
                    rd.SetParameterValue("@FECHAI", fechin, "ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt");
                    rd.SetParameterValue("@FECHAF", fechfin, "ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt");
                    rd.SetParameterValue("@CEDULA", "0930159520", "ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt");
                    //Asignarle al CrystalReportViewer el ReportDocument                         
                    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
                    SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo); 

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR REPORT: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Y por ultimo el codigo del metodo RolAdm3Mes.

```
 public static SISROLDataSetRolMensualAdmCedula RolAdm3Mes(DateTime fecini, DateTime fecfin, String Cedula)
    {

        SISROLDataSetRolMensualAdmCedula ds = new SISROLDataSetRolMensualAdmCedula();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RolMensualAdmCedula", cnn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAI", fecini.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAF", fecfin.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CEDULA", Cedula);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds,"RolMensualAdmCedula");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Espero una vez mas me brinden su conocimiento y ayuda para poder resolver este inconveniente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que tienes un informe al que le has añadido el subinforme que ya tenias hecho, pero te falta pasarle los datos del dataset.

1.Tienes que pasarle los datos al subinforme

```
private void FormReporteAdmMensual_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    try
    {
        String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            try
            {
                ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                myConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SISTEMAS-PC";
                myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "SISROL";
                myConnectionInfo.UserID = "TECNOLOGIA";
                myConnectionInfo.Password = "tecnologia";
                myConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;
                String filePath = @"Z:\Sisrol-Net\Reportes\ReporteMensualAdm3Meses.rpt";//Cargar el Reporte
                rd.Load(filePath);                       
                //Asignarle al Reporte el DataSet                    
                rd.SetDataSource(RolAdm3Mes(fechin, fechfin,"0930159520"));



 //Asignarle al Subreporte el DataSet
            rd.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(RolAdm3Mes(fechin, fechfin,"0930159520"));



rd.SetParameterValue("@FECHAI", fechin, "ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt");
        rd.SetParameterValue("@FECHAF", fechfin, "ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt");
        rd.SetParameterValue("@CEDULA", "0930159520", "ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt");
        //Asignarle al CrystalReportViewer el ReportDocument                         
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
        SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo); 

 }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR REPORT: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}

}
```

2. No puedes pasar parametros al subinforme, al menos hasta la penultima version del Crystal Reports (ya desconozco si es posible), no es posible hacer algo como:
   rd.SubReports[0].SetParameterValue("@CEDULA", "0930159520", "ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt");

Lo que tienes que hacer es vincular los campos del subinforme con los del informe principal, para eso, en el informe principal->boton derecho sobre el subinforme->Cambiar vinculos del subinforme, Y en la ventana que aparece es donde tienes que decirle que campos del informe principal quieres enlazar con los del subinforme.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @Juanjo , lo único que me faltaba era esta pequeño parte del código  rd.Subreports[0] y con eso funciono sin problemas , te agradezco por tu colaboración